# Trying to use a function in Data.Map.hs but it says not in scope ... Is it because of #if defined(TESTING)

Tags: haskell, dictionary, binary-search-tree

In [Data.Map](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/src/Data-Map.html) there are some functions like merge, glue, that I want to use but the compiler says they're not in scope. I notice at the top they are listed here:

```
#if defined(TESTING)
            -- * Internals
            , bin
            , balanced
            , join
            , merge
#endif
```

I think this means I can't use them directly unless I've somehow defined TESTING but I've no clue how to do that and where. Please answer as if I'm retarded; don't assume I know you mean to type something in the command line instead of typing it in the program.

I'm on Windows XP and using GHCi if it matters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. These functions are only meant to be used by the library's internal tests. `TESTING` is determined at compile-time, so you couldn't change it even if you wanted to.

The internal tree structure of the map shouldn't be relevant to someone using the code, so it's difficult to say what would be a better solution without some concrete information about what you're trying to do.